# Increasing TextView TextSize by 10% dynamically

Tags: android, textview, scale

One would think this would increase text size by 10%:

```
view.setTextSize( (float) (view.getTextSize() * 1.1) );
```

But unfortunately, the `get` and `set` calls operate in **different scales!**

Check this out, on a Galaxy Nexus (phone):

```
float a = view.getTextSize();  // a = 44.0
view.setTextSize(a);
float b = view.getTextSize();  // b = 88.0
```

On a Nexus7 (tablet):

```
float a = view.getTextSize();  // a = 44.0
view.setTextSize(a);
float b = view.getTextSize();  // b = 58.6
```

The `set` call scales the number I give it by some arbitrary number.

I tried calling `getScaleX()` and `getTextScaleX()` to see if I could retrieve the scale value and account for it, but both of those calls always return `1.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two methods use different units. The value returned by `getTextSize()` is in actual measured pixels while `setTextSize()` takes an argument in SPs, then measures it appropriately for the device. You need to use `view.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, a)` to do what you're looking for. The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) has more info and other unit values.

Answer (score 4):

You are absolutely correct, this is happening by design.  Let me explain:

When you pass a value into the `setTextSize()` method with a single parameter, it assumes that value is using the units of "sp", which is similar to "dp".  Both take the value and apply the scale factor appropriate for the device's resolution (1.0 for mdpi, 1.5 for hdpi, 2.0 for xhdpi).

From the TextView Documentation:

> Set the default text size to the given value, interpreted as "scaled pixel" units. This size is adjusted based on the current density and user font size preference.

When you get the value back, it is always in the raw pixel value stored.  If you want to set the text size in raw pixels as well, you should use the version of `setTextSize()` that takes two parameters so you can specify the units constant.

The Galaxy Nexus is an xhdpi device (so all scale factors are 2.0), the Nexus 7 is a tvdpi device, which has a scale factor of 1.333333.  Perhaps [this guide](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html) will help explain more.

Comment: Ahh ok.  That explains the behavior in more detail.  Thanks